# how to get the file properties in assets folder on android?

Tags: android, file, assets

I want to get the file properties in assets folder on android,But it is unlike general operation use some kinds of methods to get,anybody can help me to get the file properties such as modified date.
My assets file has a "ok.txt",please do me a help?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, I think this blog post will answer your question, with code showing example of using InputStream:

http://myossdevblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/reading-properties-files-on-android.html

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can get last modified date with [`lastModified()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29).

```
File file = new File(<file path>);
long lastModified = file.lastModified();
```

But `lastModified()` returns unix time. You can convert it with format.

```
Date date = new Date(lastModified);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation of [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class, there are lots of methods to get any kind of information about a file.

Comment: yes,I know about the File class has some methods to get the properties,such as lastModified(),but if I want to access assets file,it olny can use AssetManager to open,and then get the InputStream,such as follow: AssetManager m=this.getAssets(); InputStream in=m.open("ok.txt"); I wander that how to use InputStream to get the properties?

Comment: Did you solved? I need the lastModifiedDate property.