# File not found in project folder

Tags: java, android, path, filenotfoundexception

I have a function that loads a config.properties file from the main folder of the project, however, it gives me a FileNotFoundException and I have no idea why.
My method looks like:

```
public static Configfile configuration() {
        String server = null;
        int dbport = 0;
        String dbuser = null;
        String dbpass = null;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            prop.load(input);

            server = prop.getProperty("server");
            dbport = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("dbport"));
            dbuser = prop.getProperty("dbuser");
            dbpass = prop.getProperty("dbpassword");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return new Configfile(server, dbport, dbuser, dbpass);
    }
```

And my config.properties file is in:

> E:\Android\NSomething5

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Stacktrace:

```
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /config.properties: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at com.example.nsomething.utils.DBOperations.configuration(DBOperations.java:122)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at com.example.nsomething.utils.DBOperations.<init>(DBOperations.java:24)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at com.example.nsomething.Report.<init>(Report.java:20)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
12-04 17:00:07.619: W/System.err(21368):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: `file from the main folder of the function` ?? Sorry, I'm not aware that functions have folders. Please explain.

Comment: How are you running this code and from where?

Comment: If you use Java 7, use try-with-resources and java.nio.file. `FileNotFoundException` is useless. Post the stack trace so that we can make _sure_ that the file is indeed missing instead of not being able to access it etc

Comment: `E:\Android\NSomething5` ???/ That is no valid Android file system path. That is a Windows path. The app on your device has nothing to do with files on your pc.

Comment: @greenapps That was a mistype, I wanted to say 'of the project'.

Comment: @UriAgassi The same file, running it as 'Configfile config = configuration();'

Comment: @fge Posted the stacktrace.

Comment: @greenapps I didn't say that is an Android file system path, that is the Windows path where my file is located. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileInputStream loads the file from either the absolute path provides or relative to the 'current working directory'. Now absolute path is not relevant to your example. So FileInputStream searches for your file 'config.properties' in the 'current working directory'. This directory is normally the one from which you started the program. If you are doing this on Android, place your config file in te assets folder and use the assets API functions to load the file as a stream. If this is a standalone java program then place the file on classpath and use the classloader.getResourceAsStream to load the file. Finally if you know the absolute path to the file use it directly.

Comment: I am doing this on Android, can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
E:\Android\NSomething5
```

That is no valid Android file system path. That is a Windows path. The app on your device has nothing to do with files on your pc.

Put your config file in the assets folder of your project. Then at runtime use assetsmanager to open an InputStream and read from it. For the rest youc can use the same code. Only opening InputStream is different.

Comment: I didn't say that is an Android file system path, that is the Windows path where my file is located. I did try to place it in the 'Assets' folder and call my code like "/asset/config.properties' but it does not work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: no no. Not like "/asset/config.properties" it doesnt work like that. check this link to get an example code....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103757/how-to-get-the-file-properties-in-assets-folder-on-android

Comment: @Nazgul What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you shoudl put your cofig file in assets folder or a subfolder under it but you cant access it as "/asset/config.properties". There is no folder /asset on android that can be accessed directly. All app assets are relative to our app installation and data stuff. Check the link I gave you above. It shows the code to get Assetmanager and read a file from assets folder